# Decrementing values in one table based on occurences in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause

I am trying to update all the values in one table that exist in a second table, once for each occurence.

Example `feeding_view` table:

```
fishnr | food_name | stock
-------+-----------+-------
1      | f1        | 25
2      | f1        | 25
3      | f2        | 30
```

Example `inventory` table:

```
item_name | stock
----------+-------
f1        | 25
f2        | 30
f3        | 10
```

Currently I am trying to do this:

```
UPDATE inventory SET stock = stock - 1 WHERE item_name IN (SELECT food_name FROM feeding_view)
```

What happens is `f1` only gets decremented a single time but I want it to decrement for each each `f1` in the `feeding_view`.  So the desired stock for `f1` is 23 and for `f2` is 29  but instead `f1` is only decremented once to 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE inventory AS i
SET stock = stock - COALESCE(
            ( SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM feeding_view AS f
              WHERE  f.food_name = i.item_name
            ), 0 ) ;
```

or maybe this, not sure:

```
UPDATE 
    ( SELECT i.item_name, i.stock, f.cnt
      FROM inventory AS i
        JOIN 
          ( SELECT food_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
            FROM feeding_view
            GROUP BY food_name
          ) AS f
          ON f.food_name = i.item_name
    ) AS upd 
SET stock = stock - cnt ;
```